# nggettext - Translate a text has <a> tag inside it

Tags: angularjs, node.js, translate

I am trying to translate this text.

```html
<label class="check" translate>
   <input type="checkbox" name="tnc" ng-init="tnc=false" ng-model="tnc" /> I agree to the <a ng-click="open('terms.html')">
            Terms of Service </a> & <a ng-click="open('privacy.html')">
            Privacy Policy </a>
</label>
```

I ran 'grunt nggettext_extract' and it extracted source text as

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tnc" ng-init="tnc=false" ng-model="tnc"> I       agree to the <a ng-click="open('terms.html')">
        Terms of Service </a> & <a ng-click="open('privacy.html')">
        Privacy Policy </a>
```

and I translated it like that

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tnc" ng-init="tnc=false" ng-model="tnc"><a ng-click="open('terms.html')">
        Kullanım Şartları </a>'nı & <a ng-click="open('privacy.html')">
        Gizlilik Sözleşmesi</a>'ni kabul ediyorum
```

After that, I ran 'grunt nggettext_compile'. It said 'Done, without errors.' but in my page, it says '[MISSING]'.

How can I correct it?

Thank you.